# Communication between webserver and matlab

Tags: matlab, webserver, tcp

I have developed an app in Matlab and I want users to register it online. To do so, the matlab app requires sending/receiving data to/from a webserver. I am looking for a robust way to establish such connections. I'm good at Matlab but have no experience in TCP/IP communications or server side.Any comments, suggestions or recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: Why TCP/IP? I would prefer some higher level communication like REST (supported by matlab) XMLRPC (Available via java) or SOAP (supported at least in recent versions)

Comment: OK. thanks. how can I find something about these methods. I believe this online registration is very common and I don't want reinvent the wheel.